# Photoshop, actions or script - create and use pattern

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, photoshop-scripting, actions, script

I would like to create a pattern and use that pattern in the same action, but when I go to use fill with pattern, the last manually selected pattern is the one that is used - even if that pattern has been deleted.

If I manually click the pattern I want to use, then it becomes useless in the action, because I want to use the pattern I just created.

I'm using this for testing and saving repeated out versions of a pattern to a set document size.

I am using adobe PS CC

I currently am doing this via duplication and transforms then manually cropping, but it is incredibly time consuming because some of the patterns are at vastly different repeat sizes. (as in, it takes forever for my computer to do)

Answer (score 1):

Make a **Style** with this pattern and apply this style in the action instead filling with pattern.

**Edit after the comment**

Make a Style with this pattern:

- make a temp layer and add a **Pattern Overlay Effect**
- choose *your* pattern from the **Pattern List**
- from the **Styles Panel**, click the **New Style Icon**.

When recording the action, at the step where the fill must be applied, click the Style icon at the Styles Panel.

Comment: OK, I don't use styles much - how do I define a style as part of an action? I've googled, but the options I'm getting wont automate to the most recently created pattern.

Comment: Answer updated with the explanation

Comment: But when I do that and run the action again, it still applies the previously selected pattern when I run the action - it just creates another idential style as well.
I want to create a pattern (or style, or whatever), size the document, and then apply that pattern to the new or newly sized document.
The method you are suggesting cannot be batched.

Comment: You don't have to create the style while recording the action. Make the style before,  and then record the action. I use this method in several actions, it's not a suggestion, it's the way to make it.

Comment: but if I make the style separately Its not automated - I'd have to go into each file, make a style and record an action to apply it. Thats actually more work than just manually filling the pattern.

I am asking how to automate making AND applying the pattern.

basically I want to tile the image, not a particular pattern over a bunch of images, but each image, with itself.